# How does SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR interfer with each other?

Tags: linux, pthreads, thread-priority

SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR are both meant for real-time uses. I am aware that SCHED_RR can be preempted by time slicing. But say if I have one thread set to SCHED_FIFO, and another set to SCHED_RR, if both threads are ready to run, are they scheduled purely by priority? What if they have same priority?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conceptually, there is a list of runnable processes associated with each static priority level. These lists can contain both `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR` processes - the two scheduling policies share the same set of static priorities.

When selecting a process to run, the scheduler takes the process at the head of the non-empty list with the highest static priority, regardless of the scheduling policy of that process.

The scheduling policies affect how the processes move within those lists.  For `SCHED_FIFO`, once a process reaches the head of the list for a given priority it will stay there until it blocks or yields.  For `SCHED_RR`, a runnable process that has exceeded its maximum time quantum will be moved to the end of the list for its static priority.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment. Suppose a system has *only* three 'SCHED_RR` processes: one at priority, say, 90, and the other two at priority, say, 45. Will the process with priority 90 be scheduled over and over again at the end of its time slice, thereby starving the other two (unless it blocks)? I think so. Unless the scheduler explicitly avoids scheduling the same process once again in case there are other process to schedule.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: That is correct (if the machine has only one CPU core available).  As long as the priority 90 process is runnable, the list of runnable processes at priority 90 will be non-empty and thus the same process will be selected to run.  This is how the real-time scheduling priorities are intended to work - a lower priority process will never run if a higher priority process could be running instead.  (If there is more than one CPU core, the priority 90 process will always run and the priority 45 processes will alternate running simultaneously).